# Configure Domain and Path of CRM 2011 WIF Cookie?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, wif, adfs2.0

We have an external Web API that we use in CRM javascript. Its hosted on the same domain (different port) as CRM. I need the WebApi to authenticate IFD users, the easiest way seems to be to set the domain for the WIF cookies so they are shared across CRM and our custom site.

I can set the cookie properties via WIF config in our ASP.Net app.
How can I do the same for CRM?

Comment: I need to share the cookie, as I can't have the normal passive redirect. Background info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11777983/adfs-2-0-and-jsonp